# Filter by date today Postgres and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, filter

Currently new to Postgres and php Need help on getting current date total of trees to show

I just need to count current trees on current date but can't seem to make it work.

```
 $sql = "SELECT trees.tree_type, tree_solds.transaction_id, 
                tree_solds.actual_height, tree_solds.selling_height, 
                tree_solds.sub_total,transactions.date_purchased 
         FROM tree_solds
         LEFT JOIN trees on tree_solds.tree_id = trees.id
         LEFT JOIN transactions on transactions.id = tree_solds.transaction_id
         WHERE user_id = 8";

 $res = pg_query($sql);
 $count = pg_num_rows($res);

 echo $count;
```

Comment: Is user_id a column of "transactions" table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what is the problem, but since you say "current date" I guess you are just missing a filter by date?

```
 $sql = "SELECT trees.tree_type, tree_solds.transaction_id, 
            tree_solds.actual_height, tree_solds.selling_height, 
            tree_solds.sub_total,transactions.date_purchased 
     FROM tree_solds
     LEFT JOIN trees on tree_solds.tree_id = trees.id
     LEFT JOIN transactions on transactions.id = tree_solds.transaction_id
     WHERE user_id = 8 AND transactions.date_purchased BETWEEN current_date AND current_date + INTERVAL '1 DAY'";
```

Comment: This query turns the LEFT JOIN's into INNER JOIN's and destroys any benefit of an index on transactions.date_purchased. It's also better to use current_date (datatype date) instead of now() (datatype timestamp)

Comment: Edited replacing now() by current_date. Not sure about how would you fix the first part? I guess it would be better to avoid converting the data with DATE, but since it's not specified which is the column type, I assumed it would be a datetime/timestamp and hence the usage of DATE.

Comment: When you have a timestamp but need a result from the entire day, use a BETWEEN statement: WHERE transactions.date_purchased BETWEEN current_date AND current_date + INTERVAL '1 DAY'; An index on date_purchased can now be used